# Should I say "the reason is" or "the reason was"?

Tags: past-tense

I was wondering if you could turn the "the reason is [...]" phrase into the past tense.

Can you turn "The reason I was late *is* because I slept in this morning." to "The reason I was late *was* because I slept in this morning."?
Should I have to push it further back, such as in "The reason I was late *was* because I had slept in that morning."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are acceptable: the reason at the time *was* x and it still *is* X, and *will be* in the future.

So which you use depends on the context.

- If you’re explaining to your boss why you arrived late an hour ago, you would use *is*:

  > Gee, Mr. Sartorius, I'm sorry: the reason I was late **is** because I slept in this morning.
- If at lunch you’re telling a friend what you said to your boss, you would use *was*:

  > So I told him the reason I was late **was** because I slept in this morning.
- But if some weeks later you’re telling somebody why you got fired, you’d have to change the time reference:

  > So I told him the reason I was late **was** because I slept in **that** morning.

And by the way, you might not have been fired if you hadn’t said you *slept in*—that implies, at least in US usage, that you did it on purpose. Next time tell your new boss *I overslept*, and maybe he’ll be more forgiving!